# Tapestry overriding HibernateSessionManager error

Tags: hibernate, tapestry

I am trying to override `org.apache.tapestry5.hibernate.HibernateSessionManager`. To do this I added this to my AppModule:

```
public static void contributeServiceOverride(
        MappedConfiguration<Class<?>, Object> configuration)
{
    configuration.addInstance(HibernateSessionManager.class,
            HibernateSessionManagerOverride.class);
}
```

The content of `HibernateSessionManagerOverride` (for the time being) is the same as the default Tapestry implementation `org.apache.tapestry5.internal.hibernate.HibernateSessionManagerImpl`.

When I run my application I get this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Exception constructing service 'ServletApplicationInitializer': 
Unable to instantiate class org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule as a module: 
Exception constructing service 'ServiceOverride': 
Error invoking service contribution method com.company.services.AppModule.contributeServiceOverride(MappedConfiguration): 
Exception constructing service 'ServiceOverride': 
Construction of service 'ServiceOverride' has failed due to recursion:
the service depends on itself in some way. Please check org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.services.ServiceOverrideImpl(Map) (at ServiceOverrideImpl.java:31) via org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.services.TapestryIOCModule.bind(ServiceBinder) (at TapestryIOCModule.java:49) for references to another service that is itself dependent on service 'ServiceOverride'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at hibernateModule.java, I can see the following:

```
@Contribute(ServiceOverride.class)
public static void provideInjectableSessionObject(
        MappedConfiguration<Class, Object> configuration, 
        @HibernateCore Session session)
{
    configuration.add(Session.class, session);
}
```

Perhaps this is causing the circular dependency?

You might need to use a [decorator](http://tapestry.apache.org/tapestry-ioc-decorators.html) instead of a ServiceOverride

eg:

```
public static HibernateSessionManager decorateHibernateSessionManager(
        HibernateSessionManager defaultManager, 
        @Autobuild HibernateSessionManagerOverride overrideManager)
{
    return overrideManager;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont want to devalue Lance's answer but using this method I found that ThreadCleanupListener was not added or called which means that sessions were not being rolled back at the end of the threads lifecycle. I modified the above example to add the override as a threadcleanup listener.

```
public static HibernateSessionManager decorateHibernateSessionManager(
        HibernateSessionManager defaultManager,
        @Autobuild HibernateSessionManagerOverride overrideManager,
        PerthreadManager perthreadManager)
{
    perthreadManager.addThreadCleanupListener(overrideManager);
    return overrideManager;
}
```

this is critical so that sessions are rolled back and closed after use.